# Block a specific javascript file in a Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

Disclaimer: I've never written a Safari Extension before and I'm an utter newb at Javascript, though I do have plenty of experience in other languages.

Here's my question: I'm writing a Safari Extension to improve a certain site I visit frequently. One of the improvements I'd like to make is to block the loading of `ckeditor.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

The script is slow to load, slow to run, and I can't stand graphical HTML editors anyway.

Is it possible to create a script that will remove `ckeditor.js` before it downloads? If not, can I write something that will remove it before it runs?

Comment: @kubi - I think your question would be more likely to receive the kind of answers you are looking for if you asked at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing extension [blocking all JavaScripts on a given web page](http://homepage.mac.com/drewthaler/jsblacklist/).  This site points to two files "global.html" and "injected.js", that control whether to load the script on a per element basis.  So it looks like it is possible to modify this to blacklist specific scripts.  It might take some work to figure out the right incantation from the "beforeload" event though.